# How to read m4a file in python?

Tags: ffmpeg, pydub, m4a

I tried with the following code to read the file:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
filename = "test.m4a"
audio = AudioSegment.from_file(filename)
```

This throwed the following error:

> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001a101b24980] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!

> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001a101b24980] moov atom not found

> test.m4a: Invalid data found when processing input

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: first google answer saying us: `it indicates your file has not been downloaded/uploaded properly and has turned corrupt`

Comment: second answer gives us [details](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/ih0hf7/ffmpeg_moov_atom_not_found/)

Comment: The error and warnings seem to be cause by [tag:ffmpeg]. See also this [untrunc fix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493897/how-to-recover-a-broken-mp4-file-moov-atom-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The file was corrupted so I replaced it and it worked! Thank you the quick responses @rzlvmp and @hc_dev

Comment: I have this problem today too. Mistake is in a video file, not in code